# Converting a string date to date with added extras

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string in the following format

```
taskLastRunTime = 19:30:00, 18/02/2013
```

I want to convert this to another string but in the format

```
19:30:00, Monday 18 Feb 2013
```

I have tried using strptime but when i try the following

```
date_tasklastRunTime = time.strptime(taskLastRunTime, "%A %d %b %Y")
```

I get the following

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=19:30:00, 18/02/2013  fmt=%A %d %b %Y
```

Whats the best way of doing this (I'm using Python 2.4.1), or any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input looks like this:

```
19:30:00, 18/02/2013
```

I would think your `strptime` format string would look like this:

```
%H:%M:%S, %d/%m/%Y
```

Comment: But that is the format of the string, I want to change the format so it ends up being 19:30:00, Monday 18 Feb 2013

Comment: strptime() is a function to convert a string into a datetime object.  You can use it to parse your input as I said, then later use strftime() to convert the datetime object back to a string in your desired format.